# Setting User-Specific Configurations in Firebase Remote Config

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config

I'm working on a project where I need to enable certain configurations in Firebase Remote Config based on individual user emails. I tried couple of methods, but couldn't achieve what I want.

Approach 1 :
saving user email with **setUserProperties({ email: user?.email })** and also create email property in custom definitions.

Approach 2 :
Create a custom audience with same email definition and use the 'exactly matches' option to check valid user email IDs.

[image]

Looks like both option are not working. How to get this done using both Firebase Remote Config & Analytics. My rest of the flags are working fine except this one with condition.

Tried below code to set email of user and enable configs based on the emails:

```
const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
   setUser(user);
   setUserProperties(analytics, {
     email: user?.email,
   });
   setLoading(false);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seems to be working"? Please edit the question to provide both code and instructions that anyone can follow that duplicate your observations.

Comment: @DougStevenson question edited. Not working in the sense, The flag is set to true for particular user and it the feature is not appear.

Comment: @DougStevenson can u please check now ?